# C# trim application path

Tags: c#, file, path, startup, trim

I have this application path:

> C:\Documents and Settings\david\My Documents\app\

And a file path:

> C:\Documents and Settings\david\My Documents\app\stuff\file.txt

How can I trim the application path from the file path so it becomes stuff\file.txt? Reason being one of the command line tools I'm using doesn't support spaces in the file path.

Comment: Just a guess but have you tried wrapping the path in paranthesis `"` when supplying it to your command line tools?

Comment: I feel like an idiot, thanks for letting me know that. It works fine when enclosing the path with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Uri path = new Uri(@"C:\Documents and Settings\david\My Documents\app\stuff\file.txt");
Uri workingDirectory = new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
string relativePath = workingDirectory.MakeRelativeUri(path).ToString();
```

Related documentation:

- [Uri.MakeRelativeUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.makerelativeuri.aspx)
- [Directory.GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx)

Comment: Even though I realized I forgot to enclose the path in paranthesis, this sure will come in handy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know which command tool you are using, but normally they work if we enclosed the string/ path in quotation marks like this

"C:\Documents and Settings\david\My Documents\app\stuff\file.txt"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why normal string replace won't do:

```
string filePath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\david\My Documents\app\stuff\file.txt";
string appPath = @"C:\Documents and Settings\david\My Documents\app\";
string trimmed = filePath.Replace(appPath, "");
```

However, if you simply enclose the full path in quotes (`"`), most command line tools will be fine with spaces:

```
string escapedPath = @"""C:\Documents and Settings\david\My Documents\app\stuff\file.txt""";
```